# Is this case of replacing the plural number with the singular number correct?

Tags: grammatical-number

The below paragraph comes from article "[Die Lage am Freitag](http://www.spiegel.de/politik/deutschland/news-des-tages-a-1109372.html)" in *Der Spiegel*. Should not *mit dem Staatschef* be *mit Staatschefs* in the sentence highlighted in bold?

> Junckers stille Entmachtung
>
> Merkels Sommerreise durch Europa führt sie heute nach Warschau, wo sie
>   unter anderem die polnische Ministerpräsidentin Beata Szydlo trifft.
>   Das Auffälligste an der Reisediplomatie dieser Woche ist allerdings,
>   dass eine Stadt fehlte: Brüssel. **Merkel ist nach dem Brexit
>   erkennbar darum bemüht, einen Konsens *mit dem Staatschef* der anderen
>   EU-Länder zu finden**, EU-Kommissionschef Juncker ist in ihrem Plan
>   erst einmal nicht vorgesehen. Den will sie erst Ende nächster Woche
>   treffen, wenn die Gespräche mit Merkels Kollegen abgeschlossen sind.
>   Die Ergebnisse darf er nicht mitgestalten, sondern nur zur Kenntnis
>   nehmen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. It should be plural:

> Merkel ist nach dem Brexit erkennbar darum bemüht, einen Konsens mit **den Staatschefs** der anderen EU-Länder zu finden, ...

You also need the definite article **den** (dative plural) because they are *certain* nation leaders (you know who they are), not just *any* nation leaders.